# Данные изображения не попадают в бд но на сервер грузятся

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Скрипт на ajax + php с pdo запросами на сервер картинка попадает, но данные в бд нет. то есть каталог и имя файла

Возникает такая ошибка

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE login =
>   NULL' at line 1' in
>   /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/1/upload.php:43
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/1/upload.php(43):
>   PDOStatement->execute()
>
> #1 {main}thrown in **/home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/1/upload.php**
>   on line **43**

потом вот скрипт запроса к бд mr

```
$sqlimage = "INSERT INTO users(catalog, filename) VALUES(:catalog, :filename) WHERE login = :login";
$stmtimg = $pdo->prepare($sqlimage);
$stmtimg->bindParam(':catalog', $uploaddire, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtimg->bindParam(':filename', $comma_separated, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtimg->bindParam(':login', $_POST['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtimg->execute();
```

и на всякий случай весь код

```
<?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/registration/1/my_room/php/session.php');
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_FILES))
{
    //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
    $error = array();
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v){

        $uploaddir = 'images/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$k]);

        // Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
        if (!copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
        {

            $error[] = "<div class='dannye'><h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</div></h3>";
        }

    }

    if(count($error) == 0)
    {
        //$uploadfiles = explode(',', $uploadfilee);
        //$getMime =  $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$k];
        $uploaddire = $uploaddir;
        $comma_separated = implode(',', $uploadfilee);

        $sqlimage = "INSERT INTO users(catalog, filename) VALUES(:catalog, :filename) WHERE login = :login";
        $stmtimg = $pdo->prepare($sqlimage);
        $stmtimg->bindParam(':catalog', $uploaddire, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtimg->bindParam(':filename', $comma_separated, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtimg->bindParam(':login', $_POST['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtimg->execute();

        /*  $sqlimage = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(catalog, filename) VALUES(:catalog, :filename) WHERE login = :login");
            $sqlimage->execute(array(
                "catalog" => $uploaddire,
                "filename" => $comma_separated,
                "login" =>  $_POST['login']
        ));*/

        //выводим результат\
        if (isset($sqlimage)) {
            echo 1;
        } elseif (!$sqlimage) {
            echo 0;
        } else {
            echo "ничего не пойму";
        }
    }
    elseif (count($error) > 0){
        echo json_encode($error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите в запросе на INSERT `WHERE login = :login`, оператор WHERE не определен для конструкции INSERT.

Comment: убрал ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Koly $stmtimg->bindParam(':login', $_POST['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR); - тоже уберите или вынесите его в INSERT VALUES

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке же указано: **WHERE login = NULL**

Проверьте имена инпатов в форме, и обязательно проверяйте, есть ли вообще инфа в нужных Вам ключах массива.

```
if (!$_POST['login']){
exit("Empty Login!");
}
```